# Newtonsoft Json.NET DLLs failure on Windos8 App Certification Kit

Tags: json.net, windows-store, app-certification-kit, wack

We are trying to get our app to pass Microsoft's ACK (App Certification Kit) for Windows8 desktop applications.
However, when we run the ACK, we get the following warning reported on one of the DLLs we reference:

> File C:\Program Files\Development\Newtonsoft.Json.Net35.dll has failed
>   the APTCACheck check.

There's also a link to the following page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh750314.aspx#binscope_1

Is there any way to avoid this warning?

Thanks a lot,

Debrain

Answer (score 0):

Json.NET has a version built for Windows 8. Use the latest version of that dll.